# Use Case Statement with AND in order to filter results SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

I am trying to build a statement that will return the number of work orders worked on by each employee each day. The problem is that the employee could work on a work order multiple times in one day (which I would only count as 1), or they could work on a work order multiple times on multiple days (which i would count as 1 per day worked on).

Can I use the `Case` statement with an `AND` expression to do this? something like this:

```
SELECT    
   WKE_EmployeeID, WKE_LabDate, WKE_RecordID, 
   'WorkOrder' = CASE
                   WHEN WKE_WorkOrderID = WKE_WorkOrderID AND WKE_LabDate = WKE_LabDate 
                     THEN (Select Distinct WKE_WorkOrderID)
                   ELSE WKE_WorkOrderID
FROM         
   dbo.WKE
WHERE     
   (WKE_EmployeeID IN (N'sweda', N'bakja', N'gebwa')) 
   AND (WKE_LabDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
ORDER BY 
   WKE_WorkOrderID
```

This is just the first part of course, b/c then I need to count the workorders per employee per day, but I want to figure out how to do this part first so that I can verify my data.

Am I on the right path, or should i be looking to do this in a completely different way? Maybe sub reports?

SAMPLE DB

```
WKO employee    date
RW19800 bakja   1/6/14 12:00 AM  
RW20573 gebwa   1/2/14 12:00 AM  
RW20574 gebwa   1/2/14 12:00 AM  
RW20600 gebwa   1/10/14 12:00 AM  
**RW20602   gebwa   1/2/14 12:00 AM  
RW20602 gebwa   1/7/14 12:00 AM**  
*RW20603    bakja   1/8/14 12:00 AM  
RW20603 bakja   1/8/14 12:00 AM*
```

So for the BOLDED part of the above, I would count that as 2 instances since work was done on it 2 different days.

For the Italicized part, I would want to count that as 1 instance since work was done on it twice in the same day.

Final Output sample example:

```
date    WKO Count   employee  
1/2/14 12:00 AM 3   gebwa  
1/6/14 12:00 AM 1   bakja  
1/7/14 12:00 AM 1   gebwa  
1/8/14 12:00 AM 1   bakja  
1/10/14 12:00 AM1   gebwa
```

Comment: Sample input & output datasets please?

Comment: what datat type is `WKE_LabDate`?, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008, and i'm using Sql server mgmnt studio. WKE_LabDate is a datetime data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT WKE_EmployeeID, WKE_LabDate, COUNT(DISTINCT WorkOrderID)
FROM dbo.WKE
WHERE EmployeeID IN (N'sweda', N'bakja', N'gebwa')
  AND Date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
GROUP BY WKE_EmployeeID, WKE_LabDate
```

Comment: Hi Anon! this looks like it works for me! could you please explain why it is returning on per employee per day, but not excluding an order worked on two separate days? I have only worked within SQL for ~ 6 mos, and any additional info would be very useful to help me with improving my query logic

Comment: The `GROUP BY id,date` means the original data gets divided into separate buckets, with one bucket for every (id,date) pair you have.  The `COUNT()` will then process each bucket separately.  Using a `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` means it's only counting unique work orders for each (id,date) bucket, instead of all work orders in that bucket.

Answer (score 3):

No, you are not on the right path. This should just be done using `GROUP BY`.

It would look something like this:

```
select EmployeeID, Year, Month, Day, Count(*) as Count
from (
    --get one row per employee/workorder/day
    select EmployeeID, WorkOrderID, year(date) as Year, month(date) as Month, day(date) as Day
    from WorkOrder
    where EmployeeID in (N'sweda', N'bakja', N'gebwa')
        and date between @FromDate and @ToDate
    group by EmployeeID, WorkOrderID, year(date), month(date), day(date)
    ) a
group by EmployeeID, Year, Month, Day
```

Comment: This looks more like a comment to me

Comment: I can filter within a Group By statement?